# How to Execute first match from a grep of history in bash one liner

Tags: bash, command-history

On the command

```
history | grep vgh804
```

I get the following result.

```
   26  ssh -l vgh804 ssh-blah-blah
   29  ssh -l vgh804 ssh-blah-blah
   30  ssh -l vgh804 ssh-blah-blah
  103  ssh -l vgh804 ssh-blah-blah
  501  history | grep vgh804
```

I want to execute line 26. But i want a solution that generalizes and is a one liner.

```
var=$(history | grep vgh804 | head -n1 | awk {'print $1'}) && echo $var
```

Gives me

```
26
```

Is there any way I can combine this with the exclamation point. Something like

```
history | grep vgh804 | head -n1 | awk {'print $1'} | !
```

This however doesn't work because i can't pipe to !

Comment: `history` expansion happens before variable substitution and before xargs can add something. So I actually don't think there is a way how to do variable history expansion.

Comment: Maybe the infamous `eval` can do that but .... nothing :-)

Comment: Instead of saying "I want to execute command 26", perhaps explain in words why *that* is the command that you want to re-execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use as below only if the same ssh connection is made:

```
$!ssh
```

OR

```
$!26
```

Comment: Wouldn't `!ssh` execute entry 103? I think their idea is to run entry 26 without knowing it's number 26.

Comment: Yes ofcourse! ... thats y i mentioned if all ssh connections are same then 103 and 26 both will execute the same command. whats the difference in executing 103...

Comment: Well, presumably, in the real world scenario they could be different.

Comment: Yes i agree , only if its all same i mentioned to use !ssh or just get the number and execute it using !<history-number>